# require - no such file or directory

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

How could I fix the address inside the function “require” in my php. It troubleshoots and error saying:

Warning: require (..) failed to open stream: no such file or directory. [image: the error i get on the browser.]

[image: this is my folder structure]
 the file “db_connection.php” works perfectly fine - it has the “app_config.php” -> required but when i require the “db_connect.php” in “register_user.php” i get all this errors and the addresses do match ..

[image: this is the file tree]

[image: register_user.php file contents.]

Register user php file contains

require “../../../app_configuration/db_connect/db_connection.php”;

The contents of the db_connection is

require “../../app_configurations/definitions/app_config.php”;

[image: db_connection.php]

Comment: Your path references are incorrect.  Please post the tree layout and the contents of the PHP files (at least the require()/include() statements)

Comment: I edited the post - the error only occurs when I try to either “include” or “require” the db_connect.php and the error leads back to db_connect file when i have the app_config required inside the db_connect.

Comment: OK I can't work with screen shots, but look at Edgar's Answer.

Comment: Put slash at very first like this and check /../../../app_configuration/db_connect/db_connection.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use `../../` statements.

Use `include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/assets/app_configuration/db_connection/db_connection.php'` instead.